# Get a list of users name, email and proxyaddresses from csv in Powershell, but proxyaddress must be 1 per line

Tags: powershell, active-directory, import-csv

I am working on a script that provides an output with a specific data from some users from csv.
The csv is in the following format:

```
samacountname
User1
User2
USer3
```

This is what I've got so far, but works when I prompt a single user as expected

```
$user = Read-Host "prompt samaccountname"
$get = get-aduser -identity $user -properties * -server domain.name
$get | foreach-object { 
foreach($smtp in $_.proxyaddresses {
    $_ | select-object Name,mail,@{n="proxyaddress";e={$smtp}}
    }
} | ft -autosize

read-host "press any key to continue"
```

Output

```
Name           mail                proxyAddress
----           ----                ------------
User JohnDoe0  User0@asd.com       SMTP:User0@asd.com
User JohnDoe0  User0sec@asd.com    smtp:User0sec@asd.com
User JohnDoe1  User1@asd.com       smtp:User1@asd.com
User JohnDoe1  User1sec2asd.com    SMTP:User1sec2asd.com
```

How can I do the same with a list of users in a .csv file?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
$csv = Import-CSV -path "c:\file.csv" -encoding utf8 -delimiter ";"
$get = get-aduser -identity $user -properties * -server domain.name
$csv | foreach-object {
$get | foreach $smtp in $get.proxyaddress { 
foreach($smtp in $_.proxyaddresses {
    $_ | select-object Name,mail,@{n="proxyaddress";e={$smtp}}
    }
} | ft -autosize

read-host "press any key to continue"
```

Error:

```
Get-ADUser : Variable: '_' found in expression: $_.samaccountname is not defined.
At C:\TEMP\tivit\act\scripts\consulta dados de email\consulta proxyaddress em massa.ps1:14 char:8
+ $get = Get-ADUser -filter {samaccountname -eq $_.samaccountname} -Pro ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
 
ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the "in" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At C:\TEMP\tivit\act\scripts\consulta dados de email\consulta proxyaddress em massa.ps1:18 char:8
+ $get | foreach $smtp in $get.proxyaddresses {
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass each value of the `samAccountName` column of your CSV to `Get-ADUser`, all of this in a loop:

```bash
Import-CSV -path "c:\file.csv" -encoding utf8 | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        $user = Get-ADUser $_.samAccountName -Properties proxyAddresses, mail -Server domain.name
        $user.proxyAddresses | ForEach-Object {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Name           = $user.Name
                Mail           = $user.Mail
                ProxyAddresses = $_
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        # handle errors here (i.e.: if user couldn't be found)
        Write-Error -Exception $_
    }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly fine. I am now able to get the results as I expected

Comment: @jonas glad it helped :) you can consider accepting the answer if you think it was helpful